# How we can change facebook apprequest messages

Tags: facebook, apprequests

Is there any way to customize apprequest  message of facebook?

e.g. if a person sends request to his friend then default message comes "Shahid sent you a request in FarmVille"

here Shahid is username and FarmVille is an app name.

screenshot is given below

[screenshot http://www.ogilvyapplications.com/temp/apprequest.jpg](http://www.ogilvyapplications.com/temp/apprequest.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

You can only customise the message for where it appears in the Games and Apps dashboard, the notification in the dropdown will always have that default text. See the [Requests docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

you can see in the screenshot above that the text CAN be edited. it almost always is "... sent you a request in ..." but there are some different ones, like "... wants to include you as a professional connection in ..."

i still didnt find out how to change it though

maybe you need to add "verbs" to your apps (in this case - "include" you as a "professional connection", or something like that) and thats the only way to change the text?

Comment: So would that mean using the graphapi? I've trying to work on that as well but with no luck using it, it looks too different to use.